# Form action and its usage in Django

Tags: django, forms, web-crawler

First Quesiton:

This form submits to `demo_form?name=ABC`

```
<form action="demo_form" method="get">
  name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is there a way to make it submit to `demo_form/ABC/`?

Second Question:

Even if users don't use my form, if they use a web crawler to simply visit `demo_form?name=ABC` or `demo_form/ABC/`, it would yield the same result. I want to prevent that. What's the best way of making those two URLs only valid if the user submit the name via my form? I am learning django so hopefully the solution would work with django framework.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it submit to demo_form/ABC/?

You could intercept the submission in JavaScript, construct the URL manually, then set `location`. That would break if JS wasn't available.

More sanely, you could send an HTTP 301 redirect response when you get the request for `demo_form?name=ABC`

> What's the best way of making those two URLs only valid if the user submit the name via my form?

Generally speaking, visiting a form should not be a pre-requisite for anything involving a GET request. A large portion of the point of GET is that the results are bookmarkable, linkable, etc.

It would be more understandable if it was a POST request, as those are intended to change data on the server and you will want to protect against [CSFR](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29). The standard protection against CSRF is a [token stored in the form and in a cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern)